# How to go one level back directory during untar the tar file in python

Tags: python, tar, compression

I'm trying to extract tar.gz using `import tarfile` actually problem is
in the folder1.tar.gz there are one dirctory and some files 
like folder1.tar.gz->folder2->abc.txt,def.txt,folder3

```
import tarfile
tar=tarfile.open('folder1.tar.gz')
tar.extractall(targetdirectory)
```

it extract abc.txt,def.txt,folder3 in folder2 in my targetdirectory
but I want abc.txt,def.txt,folder3 in my targetdirectory not want folder 2, I want to exclude folder2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the archive structure then you can use [TarFile.getmembers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getnames) in conjunction with [TarFile.extractfile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) to get what you want. You can do something like this

```
import tarfile
tar=tarfile.open('folder1.tar.gz')
for member in tar.getmembers():
  if member.name.startswith('folder2/') and member.isfile():
    inputfile = tar.extractfile(member)
    with open(os.path.join(targetdirectory, member.name.replace('folder2/', '')), 'wb') as outputfile:
      outputfile.write(inputfile.read())
    inputfile.close()
```